# Hugin / PTGui add blur or fill to stitched 360 panoramic photo

Tags: 360-panorama, hugin

When stitching 360 panoramic photos using either Hugin or PTGui, there's often cases where there are black spaces for missing or unstitched photos. Is it possible to use either one of the software to fill in the empty spaces with a blur or something like content aware fill?

If Hugin or PTGui can't do this, is there any other similar software that can batch stitch 360 panoramic photos that has this feature?

Thank You!

Comment: Gimp has a content-aware plugin called `resynthesize`.  And IIRC there is a similar function in the GMIC filter suite for Gimp (https://gmic.eu/).

Comment: Thank you for the link! Does Gimp support batch photo stitching tasks? e.g. I need to stitch multiple 360 photos from a folder of regular photos.